# Interact with WebGL scene from independent elements

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, canvas, three.js, webgl

Is it possible to interact with a scene in WebGL (programmed with three.js) from other elements on a webpage? For example manipulate a scene on the WebGL canvas from an independent canvas or using a standard form with some javascript to add objects to the scene.

If this is possible, how well does it fit in with using MV* frameworks like angular.js or backbone.js? I've read up on their data-binding features but is this data-binding restricted to HTML on a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interact with and manipulate WebGL/Three.js just as any other dynamic element on a web page. The APIs have pretty much nothing to do with HTML DOM though, so any libraries that manipulate or expect specific DOM structures are not much help. AngularJS seems to be much about manipulating and extending DOM, for example.

You probably need to code the scene manipulation part between Three.js and your framework yourself, as Three.js scenes have DOM-like tree structure but the API is completely different from HTML DOM.

It all depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve.